# $\mathsf{Spec} \: \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(XY^2-m)\cong \mathsf{Spec} \: \mathbb{Q}[X,1/X]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

How I can prove that $\mathsf{Spec} \: \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(XY^2-m)$ is isomorphic (as scheme) to $\mathsf{Spec} \: \mathbb{Q}[X,1/X]$?

This is an example from *Algebraic Geometry and Aritmethic Curves* - Qing Liu.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, we have $R[T]/(fT-1) \cong R[\frac{1}{f}]$. In our case we get

$$\mathbb Q[X,Y]/(XY^2-m) = \mathbb Q[X,Y]/(\frac{Y^2}{m}X-1) \cong \mathbb Q[Y,\frac{m}{Y^2}] = \mathbb Q[Y,\frac{1}{Y^2}] = \mathbb Q[Y,\frac{1}{Y}].$$

Comment: And what is the canonical morphism $\mathsf{Spec} \: \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(XY^2-m) \to \mathsf{Spec} \: \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Every scheme has a canonical and unique morphism $X \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$, because $\mathbb Z$ is the initial object of commutative rings.

Comment: Yes but this is the definition, I'm asking what it is here in practice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_schemes is hard to follow

Comment: Thisi is induced by the canonical injection $\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(XY^2-1)$.

Comment: You should think about that map as a map, which sends a point of a scheme to the characteristic of its residue field.

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro So $I \mapsto I \cap \mathbb{Z}$, and we can inject the residue fields of $\mathbb{Z}$ in those of $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(XY^2-1)$ ?

Comment: This morphim take a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $Z[X,Y]/(XY^2-m)$ and takes it to $\mathfrak{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes! It's right :)